# Multiple ChangeNotifierProxyProviders to feed updates into ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier, flutter-change-notifier-provider

I have three `ChangeNotifierProvider` providers, let's call them `A`, `B` and `C`.

What I need is for changes in providers `A` and `B` to update provider `C`, but the code below isn't working.

```dart
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => A()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => B()),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<A, C>(
      create: (context) => C(),
      update: (_, a, c) => c!..updateFromA(a),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<B, C>(
      create: (context) => C(),
      update: (_, b, c) => c!..updateFromB(b),
    ),
  ]
```

I think the reason why it doesn't work is because I end up with multiple copies of provider `C`, but I am not sure how to fix it or what a better alternative implementation would look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some searching, I realized that Flutter provides an elegant out-of-the-box way of solving this problem using `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider2`.

```dart
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => A()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => B()),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider2<A, B, C>(
      create: (context) => C(),
      update: (_, a, b, c) => c!..updateFromA(a)..updateFromB(b),
    ),
  ]
```

Flutter also provides `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider3` through `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider6`, but that would, of course, get very verbose and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If having more than one instance of C is the problem, then I think you can just use `Provider.of<C>(context)` to get a single instance.

```dart
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => A()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => B()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => C()),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<A, C>(
      create: (context) => Provider.of<C>(context),
      update: (_, a, c) => c!..updateFromA(a),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<B, C>(
      create: (context) => Provider.of<C>(context),
      update: (_, b, c) => c!..updateFromB(b),
    ),
  ]
```

Or else, you could apply the singleton pattern to C:

```
class C {
  static final C _instance = C._();

  factory C() {
    return _instance;
  }

  C._();
}
```

```dart
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => A()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => B()),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<A, C>(
      create: (context) => C(),
      update: (_, a, c) => c!..updateFromA(a),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<B, C>(
      create: (context) => C(),
      update: (_, b, c) => c!..updateFromB(b),
    ),
  ]
```

Comment: Passing `false` to the named parameter `listen` when calling `Provider.of<...>(...)` is necessary in the first solution, and even with that correction it barely works. Updates are done but not without Flutter complaining of "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.". I was hopeful it could work since using any `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider...` variant doesn't fit in my case from the important amount of substates that needs to be watched, but this definitely won't work, at least not without improvements